# Cannot push due to pre-push hook failure (exit 1)

Tags: git, github, branch, git-lfs, gitkraken

Whenever I try to push (fast-forward), I receive an error saying:

> 'Pre-push hook failed: Git hook exited with 1'

The error log says:

> 'The System cannot find the path specified. Hook process exited.'

I use Git v2.38.1 and Git LFS v3.2.0. I'm using GitKraken (version 8.10.1) as a Git client.

My operating system is Windows 10 Home edition.

My repository has LFS initialized and working. The issue is with trying to push while checked out in a specific branch, as other branches have no problems with this (more about that below).

My Git pre-push file hasn't been modified and I've tried multiple times to update and force update all hooks. I've also tried deleting the pre-push file and recreating it.

Contents of my pre-push file:

```
command -v git-lfs >/dev/null 2>&1 || { echo >&2 "\nThis repository is configured for Git LFS 
but 'git-lfs' was not found on your path. 
If you no longer wish to use Git LFS, remove this hook by deleting '.git/hooks/pre-push'.\n"; exit 2; }
git lfs pre-push "$@"
```

I've also tried editing my git config file and changing the remote `origin` url from `'https://github.com/<username>/<project>.git'` to `'git@github.com/<username>/<project>.git'`, but that only had GitKraken keep asking me for my SSH credentials whenever I tried to push my changes, and I don't want to set that up for this project.

Here's my git config file:

```
    bare = false
    repositoryformatversion = 0
    filemode = false
    symlinks = false
    ignorecase = true
    logallrefupdates = true
[remote "origin"]
    url = https://github.com/<omitted>/<omitted>.git
    fetch = +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/origin/*
[branch "master"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/master
[branch "main"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/main
[lfs]
    repositoryformatversion = 0
[filter "lfs"]
    required = true
    clean = git-lfs clean -- %f
    smudge = git-lfs smudge -- %f
    process = git-lfs filter-process
[lfs "https://github.com/<omitted>/<omitted>.git/info/lfs"]
    access = basic
[branch "development"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/development
[branch "demo"]
    remote = origin
    merge = refs/heads/demo
```

How the issue began:

I created a new local branch called `'demo'` off of my `'development'` branch to make changes which I'd merge later with `'development'`. This was just a precaution as one of my colleagues made a lot of uncommitted changes within the `'development'` branch and I didn't want to risk breaking anything later on.

Anyway, after I've made a few commits, I tried pushing via GitKraken to remote (`origin/demo`), which was meant to create a remote `'demo'` branch and then push my changes to it. That is where the error first appeared. Like I've mentioned above, I've tried several fixes to no avail. I even tried making a remote branch on GitHub and then pushing again to it, now that a remote branch exists, but it didn't change anything.

### Update

Pushing my changes to remote via terminal works without giving any errors. If I try pushing new changes through GitKraken again, I'm now met with both post-commit and pre-push hook errors with the same log message as before.

If it's a problem with the hooks after all (although it shouldn't be), reinstalling GitKraken wouldn't make a difference. My guess is this is a bug, however, but either way if I reinstall I'll know for sure, so I'll make another update once that's done.

### Update 2

Once again, I tried force updating hooks and I've completely reinstalled GitKraken, but the problem persists whenever I try to push changes through the client. Doing the same through the terminal creates no errors and it goes through normally.

### Update 3

It's been 7 months now and this issue is still not fixed for me. I've since updated Git to 2.41.0, Git LFS to v3.3.0 and GitKraken to current latest version 9.5.1 (20/06/2023)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: To confirm the error comes from `git LFS pre-push`, you can run it from your she'll. A pre-push hook expects to read it's parameters from stain ([docs here](https://git-scm.com/docs/githooks#_pre_push)) : `echo "refs/heads/master <commit sha> refs/heads/master <origin/master sha>" | git lfs pre-push`

Comment: @LeGEC Thank you for your reply! I've tried pushing my changes normally through the terminal and it worked - no errors - but it remains to be seen if this occurs again through GitKraken. It might've been just a bug with the client instead.

I'll get back to you once I make some commits and try pushing through the client again.

Comment: Do you have a way to open a shell from git kraken ? It could be an issue with how git kraken sets up its environment (user account, 'PATH` ...)

Comment: @LeGEC GitKraken has an in-built terminal with a few commands you can use to control it: https://gyazo.com/deddcbff765dfb52f3c9855bd4984038
https://gyazo.com/2d1002ecb0f0c12d0135c816ddbb1d65

Comment: ok, and you have access to a `gk` command, but isn't that a complete shell ? does `echo $SHELL` work ? or `echo "foobar" | grep foo` ? `ls` ? `pwd` ?

Comment: @LeGEC I should clarify I'm using Windows 10.  Typing `echo $SHELL` does nothing and `grep` does not work as it does not exist here. I also don't use the Windows Subsystem for Linux or WSL2.